# Automatic geo-referencing options - mosaic dataset footprints?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, georeferencing, mosaic-dataset

I have 50 Jpgs that represent a route and I want to automatically georeference them. I have previously georeferenced 50 jpgs that exactly match the image extents and created a mosaic dataset. I would simply copy and rename the .jgwx/xml files and this almost works, but I am assuming because the resolutions of the jpegs are different this is offsetting them slightly.

Is there a way of automating this possibly using previous mosaic footprints?

I also can't re-export them from source to match resolutions.